# clustering algorithm with minimum number of points

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to separate a data set that has 2 clusters that do not overlap in anyway and a single data point that is away from these two clusters.

When I use kmeans() to get the 2 clusters, it splits one of the "valid" cluster into half and considers the single data point as a separate cluster.

Is there a way to specify minimum number of points for this? I am using MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions:

1. Easy: try with 3 clusters;
2. Easy: remove the single data point (that you can detect as an outlier with any outlier detection technique;
3. To be tried: Use a k-medoids approach instead of k-means. This sometimes helps getting rid of outliers.
4. More complicated but surely works: Perform [spectral clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_clustering). This helps you get over the main issue of k-means, which is the brutal use of the euclidian distance

More explanations on the inadequate behaviour of k-means can be found on Cross Validated site (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/214362/trouble-in-understanding-outliers-influence-on-k-means) for instance).